# What do you call those "observation" beds you see in vet clinics?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you calls these "observation" beds?

[image]

I think they aren't *hospital beds* because a veterinary clinic isn't technically a hospital?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with medical / veterinary jargon rather than everyday English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call that an *examination table*. You can Google for more images if you run a search using the term "*veterinary examination table".*

Comment: Of course, it is possible that a table of this type could be used for carrying out operations too (which is certainly suggested by the bags of saline hanging above it, and by the powerful lamp directed downwards towards the table). If that was its main purpose, you would call it an *operating table*. (I notice also that the table has what I assume is a gutter for collecting body fluids that runs close to all four edges of the table.) However, the most mysterious thing about this photo is that all seven of the women appear to be identical in every way except for how they are standing...

Comment: yeah, that's freaky - like something out of the X-Files!

Comment: With all due respect, @ErikKowal, this is not an [examination table.](http://www.medicalexpo.com/medical-manufacturer/veterinary-examination-table-9533.html)

Answer (score 1):

What is pictured is a surgical suite, and the metal table in the foreground is a [*surgery table.*](http://www.shor-line.com/index.php/products/productlist/81.html) (Shor-Line is one of the leading providers of veterinary hospital [yes, they are called hospitals] equipment in the U.S.)